# Spring tests - mock returns null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking

I have a small issue with mocking methods . Where mock should return an predefined object, it returns null. here is test set up:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserControllerTest {

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext webContext;
@MockBean
UserTransferService userTransferService;
@MockBean
UserService userService;
MockMvc mockMvc;

private User user = DummyObjects.getDummyUser();
private User modifiedUser = DummyObjects.getModifiedUser();
private UserTO userTO = DummyObjects.getDummyUserTO();
private UserTO modifiedUserTO = DummyObjects.getModifiedUserTO();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(modifiedUser);
    users.add(user);
    given(this.userTransferService.getTO(user)).willReturn(userTO);
    given(this.userTransferService.getObject(userTO)).willReturn(user);
    given(this.userTransferService.getTO(modifiedUser)).willReturn(modifiedUserTO);
    given(this.userTransferService.getObject(modifiedUserTO)).willReturn(modifiedUser);
    given(this.userService.findAll()).willReturn(users);
    given(this.userService.save(user)).willReturn(user);
    given(this.userService.removeById(1)).willReturn(true);
    given(this.userService.getById(1)).willReturn(user);
    given(this.userService.getById(2)).willReturn(null);
    given(this.userService.modify(modifiedUser)).willReturn(modifiedUser);
    given(this.userService.findByLogin(user.getLogin())).willReturn(user);
    given(this.userService.findByLogin("AAA")).willReturn(null);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webContext)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

test itself:

```
    @Test
public void shouldAddUser() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/user")
                    .content(TestingUtility.asJsonString(userTO))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .with(csrf().asHeader()))
            .andExpect(status().is(200))
            .andExpect(content().json(TestingUtility.asJsonString(userTO)));
}
```

and Controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public UserTO modifyUser(@RequestBody UserTO userTO, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal) throws  IllegalAccessException{
    User user = userTransferService.getObject(userTO);
    if (principal.getName().equals(userTO.getLogin()) || permissionService.hasPermission(principal,Permission.SU)) {
        return userTransferService.getTO(userService.modify(user));
    } else {
        throw new IllegalAccessException("You are not allowed to modify user");
    }
}
```

User is null, but UserTO is filled. So mocked method UserTransferService.getObject(userTO) is not working properly.

Comment: Does UserTO (or is it OrderTO?) define an equals() (and hashCode()) method(s)? If not, then the userTO that your methid receives as argument, created by deserializing the JSON, can't possibly be equal to the UserTO (or OrderTO?) defined in your test. If UserTO and OrderTO are indeed two separate classes, how could an instance of one be equal to an instance of the other?

Comment: Sorry, i've pasted wrong setup. Currently it is correct one. Yes they implement those methods.

Comment: The `UserTO` you are using in the mocking isn't the same `UserTO` as the controller is using. You are actually calling a method which means the `UserTO` is serialized/deserialized making it different objects. Which makes the mocking pretty much obsolete as it doesn't match and the default behavior is to return `null`. Basically it works as it should.

Comment: @M.Deinum not if UserTO properly overrides equals() and hashCode().

Comment: @M.Deinum So how i should avoid this and write proper mocked test in future?

Comment: As hinted by @JBNizet your `UserTO` should implement a proper `equals` and `hashCode` with that in place it should work. Else write a more expressive matcher matching on properties of your `UserTO` instead of the full object itself.